# Why does LF and CRLF behave differently with /^\s*$/gm regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, newline, carriage-return, linefeed

I've been seeing this issue on Windows. When I try to clear any whitespace on each line on Unix:

```js
const input =
`===

HELLO

WOLRD

===`
console.log(input.replace(/^\s+$/gm, ''))
```

This produces what I expect:

```
===

HELLO

WOLRD

===
```

i.e. if there were  spaces on blank lines, they'd get removed.
On the other hand, on Windows, the regex clears the WHOLE string. To illustrate:

```js
const input =
`===

HELLO

WOLRD

===`.replace(/\r?\n/g, '\r\n')
console.log(input.replace(/^\s+$/gm, ''))
```

(template literals will always print only `\n` in JS, so I had to replace with `\r\n` to emulate Windows (`?` after `\r` just to be sure for those who don't believe). The result:

```
===
HELLO
WOLRD
===
```

The whole line is gone! But my regex has `^` and `$` with the `m` flag set, so it's kind of `/^-to-$/m`. What's the difference between `\r` and `\r\n` then that makes it produce different results?

when I do some logging

```js
console.log(input.replace(/^\s*$/gm, (m) => {
  console.log('matched')
  return ''
}))
```

With \r\n I'm seeing

```
matched
matched
matched
matched
matched
matched
===
HELLO
WOLRD
===
```

and with \n only

```
matched
matched
matched
===

HELLO

WOLRD

===
```

Comment: Pretty sure that `$` will match immediately *before* the end of the line, so if you have `text\r\n` then `$` will match before `\n` but after `\r`.

Comment: so why is it logging 6 times with \r\n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** a pattern including whitespace *and* line breaks will also match characters part of a `\r\n` sequence, if you let it.

First of all, let's actually examine what characters are there and aren't there when you do a replacement. Starting with a string that only uses line feeds:

```js
const inputLF =
`===

HELLO

WOLRD

===`.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\n");

console.log('------------ INPUT ')
console.log(inputLF);
console.log('------------')

debugPrint(inputLF, 2);
debugPrint(inputLF, 3);
debugPrint(inputLF, 4);
debugPrint(inputLF, 5);

const replaceLF = inputLF.replace(/^\s+$/gm, '');

console.log('------------ REPLACEMENT')
console.log(replaceLF);
console.log('------------')

debugPrint(replaceLF, 2);
debugPrint(replaceLF, 3);
debugPrint(replaceLF, 4);
debugPrint(replaceLF, 5);

console.log(`charcode ${replaceLF.charCodeAt(2)} : ${replaceLF.charAt(2)}`);
console.log(`charcode ${replaceLF.charCodeAt(3)} : ${replaceLF.charAt(3)}`);
console.log(`charcode ${replaceLF.charCodeAt(4)} : ${replaceLF.charAt(4)}`);
console.log(`charcode ${replaceLF.charCodeAt(5)} : ${replaceLF.charAt(5)}`);

console.log('------------')
console.log('inputLF === replaceLF :', inputLF === replaceLF)

function debugPrint(str, charIndex) {
  console.log(`index: ${charIndex}
   charcode: ${str.charCodeAt(charIndex)}
   character: ${str.charAt(charIndex)}`
 );
}
```

Each line ends with char code 10 which is the Line Feed (LF) character that is represented in a string literal with `\n`. Before and after the replacement, the two strings are the same - not only *look* the same but *actually* equal each other, so the replacement did nothing.

Now let's examine the other case:

```js
const inputCRLF =
`===

HELLO

WOLRD

===`.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\r\n")
console.log('------------ INPUT ')
console.log(inputCRLF);
console.log('------------')

debugPrint(inputCRLF, 2);
debugPrint(inputCRLF, 3);
debugPrint(inputCRLF, 4);
debugPrint(inputCRLF, 5);
debugPrint(inputCRLF, 6);
debugPrint(inputCRLF, 7);

const replaceCRLF = inputCRLF.replace(/^\s+$/gm, '');;

console.log('------------ REPLACEMENT')
console.log(replaceCRLF);
console.log('------------')

debugPrint(replaceCRLF, 2);
debugPrint(replaceCRLF, 3);
debugPrint(replaceCRLF, 4);
debugPrint(replaceCRLF, 5);

function debugPrint(str, charIndex) {
  console.log(`index: ${charIndex}
   charcode: ${str.charCodeAt(charIndex)}
   character: ${str.charAt(charIndex)}`
 );
}
```

This time each line ends with char code 13 which is the Carriage Return (CR) character that is represented in a string literal with `\r` and *then* the LF follows. After the replacement, instead of having a sequence of `=\r\n\r\nH` instead it's not just `=\r\nH`. Let's look at why.

[Here is what MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#Types) about the meta character `^`:

> Matches the beginning of input. If the multiline flag is set to true, also matches immediately after a line break character.

And here is what MDN says about the meta character `$`

> Matches the end of input. If the multiline flag is set to true, also matches immediately before a line break character.

So they match *after* and *before* a line break character. In that, MDN means the LF *or* the CR. This can be seen if we test a string that contains different line breaks:

```js
const stringLF = "hello\nworld";
const stringCRLF = "hello\r\nworld";

const regexStart = /^\s/m;
const regexEnd = /\s$/m;

console.log(regexStart.exec(stringLF));
console.log(regexStart.exec(stringCRLF));

console.log(regexEnd.exec(stringLF));
console.log(regexEnd.exec(stringCRLF));
```

If we try to match whitespace near a line break, this doesn't match anything if there is an LF but it *does* match the CR with CRLF. So, in that case `$` would match here:

```
"hello\r\nworld"
        ^^ what `^\s` matches

"hello\r\nworld"
      ^^ what `\s$` matches
```

So both `^` and `$` recognise either of the CRLF sequence as end of line. This will make a difference when you do a search and replace. Since your regex specifies `^\s+$` that means that when you have a line that is entirely `\r\n` then *it matches*. But for a reason that is not obvious:

```js
const re = /^\s+$/m;

const sringLF = "hello\n\nworld";
const stringCRLF = "hello\r\n\r\nworld";


console.log(re.exec(sringLF));
console.log(re.exec(stringCRLF));
```

So, the regex doesn't match an`\r\n` but rather `\n\r` (two whitespace characters) between two other line breakcharacters. That's because `+` is eager and will consume as much of the character sequence as it can get away with. Here is what the regex engine will try. Somewhat simplified for brevity:

```
input = "hello\r\n\r\nworld
regex = /^\s+$/

Step 1
hello[\r]\n\r\nworld
    matches `^`, symbol satisfied -> continue with next symbol in regex

Step 2
hello[\r\n]\r\nworld
    matches `^\s+` -> continue matching to satisfy `+` quantifier

Step 3
hello[\r\n\r]\nworld
    matches `^\s+` -> continue matching to satisfy `+` quantifier

Step 4
hello[\r\n\r\n]world
    matches `^\s+` -> continue matching to satisfy `+` quantifier

Step 5
hello[\r\n\r\nw]orld
    does not match `\s` -> backtrack

Step 6
hello[\r\n\r\n]world
    matches `^\s+`, quantifier satisfied -> continue to next symbol in regex

Step 7
hello[\r\n\r\nw]orld
    does not match `$` in `^\s+$` -> backtrack

Step 8
hello[\r\n\r\n]world
    matches `^\s+$`, last symbol satisfied -> finish
```

Lastly, there is something slightly hidden here - it matters that you're matching whitespace. This is because it will behave differently to most other symbols in that it explicitly matches a line break character, whereas [`.` will not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes):

> Matches any single character *except* line terminators

So, if you specify `\s$` this *will* match the CR in `\r\n` because the regex engine is forced to look for a match for both `\s` and `$`, therefore it finds the `\r` before the `\n`. However, this will not happen for many other patterns, since `$` will usually be satisfied when it's *before* CR (or at the end of the string).

Same with `^\s` it will explicitly look for a whitespace character *after* a linebreak which is satisfied by the LF in CRLF, however if you're not seeking that, then it will happily match after the LF:

```js
const stringLF = "hello\nworld";
const stringCRLF = "hello\r\nworld";

const regexStartAll = /^./mg;
const regexEndAll = /.$/gm;

console.log(stringLF.match(regexStartAll));
console.log(stringCRLF.match(regexStartAll));

console.log(stringLF.match(regexEndAll));
console.log(stringCRLF.match(regexEndAll));
```

So, all of this means that `^\s+$` has some unintuitive behaviour yet perfectly coherent once you understand that the regex engine matches *exactly* what you tell it to.

Comment: To better understand this it helps to replace the anchors with two characters: `console.log('===\r\n\r\nHELLO\r\n \r\nWOLRD\r\n==='.replace(/^$/gm, 'xy'))`

Comment: I suggest you add a `TL;DR;` at the top.

Comment: Long story short, `/^/m` will match `\r` on windows, instead of full `\r\n`...  thanks for such detailed answer.