# Regular expression and \n EOL on the end of tested string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, eol

I have simple regex **^[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]*$**

I test it in .NET like this:

```
Regex.IsMatch(description, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]*$")
```

I do not understand why when there is "\n" EOL char on the end of the string then why this string matches. Or - how should the correct regex that is ignoring \n on the end would look like?

Examples:

"abc .123," - matches

"abc .123,\n" - matches, **but WHY?**

"abc\n .123," - does not match

But if I test this regex e.g. on http://regexstorm.net/tester the same string with \n on the end DOES NOT match (which I hope is correct).

Thank You all.

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60730367/

Comment: Just trim-end the NL

Comment: Use `\z` instead of `$`.

Comment: You regex matches empty lines. The text ending with `\n` has two lines with second one being empty so it matches no matter what you put in front of the `\n`